# How to handle AggregateException from Lambda function in Statemachine

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-step-functions

I have `async` lambda function. Any exception occurs inside the lambda function gets wrapped as `AggregateException`. So if state machine is invoking this lambda, it receives it as `AggregateException`

```
[assembly: LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializer))]

namespace MyFunction
{
    public class MyHandler
    {
        public Payload DoWork(Payload payload, ILambdaContext context)
        {
           throw new MyCustomException("This is test");
        }
    }
}
```

below is my state machine

```
{  
  "StartAt": "DoWork",
  "States": {        
     "DoWork":{      
      "Type":"Task",
      "Resource":"arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:xxxxx:function:MyHandler:dev",
      "Next":"OK",
       "Catch": [
         {
            "ErrorEquals": [ "MyCustomException" ],
            "Next": "HandleMyCustomException"
          },
          {
            "ErrorEquals": [ "States.ALL" ],
            "Next": "HandleAllErrors"
          }
      ]
    },       
    "HandleAllErrors": {      
      "Type": "Fail",
      "Cause": "UnknownError",
      "Error": "Unable to perform work."      
    },
    "HandleMyCustomException":{      
      "Type":"Fail",
      "Cause":"MyCustomError",
      "Error":"An unknown error occurred while processing. Please check the logs."
    },
    "OK": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Result": "The request has succeeded.",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

since state machine is receiving `AggregateException` not `MyCustomException`, it  never executes `HandleMyCustomException` step

How do we handle this. I am using .NET Core 2.0 to develop lambda function

Answer (score 1):

found

https://github.com/aws/aws-lambda-dotnet/issues/211#issuecomment-459454290

I have updated my lambda project to to .NET Core 2.1 and then added environment variable `UNWRAP_AGGREGATE_EXCEPTIONS` with value `1`

Answer (score 0):

You have to catch the right exception - the one your code is throwing. You write that all exceptions are wrapped as `AggregateException`, so just catch that in the state machine. Replace `"ErrorEquals": [ "MyCustomException" ]` with `"ErrorEquals": [ "AggregateException" ]`.